Is there a Relation for Exponentiation Similar to $\leq$ or $\backslash$ (divisibility)?
I'm trying to define common mathematical options on the natural numbers.
I am doing this because operations like subtraction are commonly constructed as just the addition of the inverse, however this doesn't apply to Natural numbers despite being taught as kids to subtract with simple (Natural) Numbers.
Every binary operation $\circ:X^2\to X$ induces a relation $R\subseteq X^2$ such that ...
$$R=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X^2|\exists z\in X(y\circ z=x)\}$$
For $\langle\mathbb{N},+\rangle$ this relation is:
$$\leq=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in \mathbb{N}^2|\exists z\in\mathbb{N}(y+z=x)\}$$
This makes it simple to define a inverse (partial) operation
$$-:\mathbb{N}^2\rightharpoonup\mathbb{N}$$
As a function with domain $\geq$.
$$-:\geq\to\mathbb{N}$$
Of course, we call this subtraction:
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{N}\forall y\leq x$$
$$((x+y)-y=x=(x-y)+y)$$
The same is true for multiplication, divisibility, and non-Euclidean division.
$\backslash=$
$$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathbb{N}^+\times\mathbb{N}|\exists z\in\mathbb{N}(y\times z=x)\}$$
$$\div:\mathbb{N}^2\rightharpoonup\mathbb{N}$$
$$\div:\backslash^\mathrm{T}\to\mathbb{N}$$
Interestingly enough these relations, or a restriction on them form lattices.
I want to use a similar relation to define the domain of $n$-root and logarithm (the right and left inverse operations defined by the right and left cancellativity of exponentiation respectively).
$$R=$$
$$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathbb{N}^+\times\mathbb{N}|\exists z\in\mathbb{N}(z^x=y)\}$$
$$L=$$
$$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in[2..)\times\mathbb{N}|\exists z\in\mathbb{N}(x^z=y)\}$$
This would make it so we could write:
$\sqrt{\phantom x}:R\to\mathbb{N}$
$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N}\forall nRx$
$(^n\sqrt{x}=y\iff y^n=x)$
$\text{log}:L\to\mathbb{N}$
$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N}\forall nLx$
$(\text{log}_n(x)=y\iff n^y=x)$
As opposed to:
$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N}\forall n(\langle n,x\rangle\in$
$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathbb{N}^+\times\mathbb{N}|\exists z\in\mathbb{N}(z^x=y)\}$
$\implies(^n\sqrt{x}=y\iff y^n=x))$
$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N}\forall n(\langle n,x\rangle\in$
$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in[2..)\times\mathbb{N}|\exists z\in\mathbb{N}(x^z=y)\}$
$\implies(\text{log}_n(x)=y\iff n^y=x))$$
Point being, if there is such (named and notated) relations, it would be a massive help defining partial inverse operations for exponentiation. So I again ask do they exist?

What do you mean by $\div:\mathbb N^2\to\mathbb N?$

$\div:\mathbb{N}^2\rightharpoonup\mathbb{N}$, where $\rightharpoonup$ indicates a partial binary operation. In other words division is a function defined on some but not necessarily all pairs of natural numbers.
